# ssh agent forwarding inside cron jobs

Tags: linux, ssh

I wonder why ssh agent forwarding does not work in cron jobs. I have a simple script such as:

```
ssh -A remote_host "ls ~"
```

I can run this script without any password typing, but after putting it inside a cron job, it always failed with:

```
Permission denied, please try again.

Received disconnect from ip_of_remote_host: 2: Too many authentication failures for myuser
```

Can anyone please tell me how to fix this issue?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: How often is the job running?  Is it a lot?  I suspect that the problem is with the environment.  The environment cron jobs run in is very different from your normal environment.  Is it the same user account?  E.g. if the cron job is running as root, it won't have your private key available for passwordless ssh.  This might sound silly, but are you sure that the shell is getting the right command passed to it?

Comment: It should be the same user account? At least I created the cron job with that same user account as I executed the script. BTW, how to check this?

Comment: I actually confirm in the cron job that the executing user is the same by using the command `whoami`

Comment: What distribution are you using?  I had no trouble doing something like this on XUbuntu 12.4.  Are you sure that the quotation marks around "ls ~" are being parsed correctly?  By default the command would be run in the home folder, so you should be able to do `ssh -A remote_host ls` also.  Also, see if you can get more information by passing one of -v / -vv / -vvv to ssh.

Comment: I did some debug, it says `debug3: Not a RSA1 key file /home/myuser/.ssh/id_dsa.`

Answer (score 2):

you need store SSH_AGENT_PID or SSH_AUTH_SOCK in a env file when your start ssh-agent, and source it in your ssh script,

Here is a script I used, grabbed from web long time ago.

```
SSH_ENV=$HOME/.ssh/environment
function start_agent {
     echo "Initialising new SSH agent..."
     /usr/bin/ssh-agent | sed 's/^echo/#echo/' > ${SSH_ENV}
     echo succeeded
     chmod 600 ${SSH_ENV}
     . ${SSH_ENV} > /dev/null
     ssh-add id_rsa
}
if [ -f "${SSH_ENV}" ]; then
     . ${SSH_ENV} > /dev/null
     ps -ef | grep ${SSH_AGENT_PID} | grep ssh-agent$ > /dev/null || {
         start_agent;
     }
else
     start_agent;
fi
```

run it manually if key is passphase protected, and it will store in the $HOME/.ssh/environment something like

```
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-KldGwK6643/agent.6643; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
SSH_AGENT_PID=6644; export SSH_AGENT_PID;
```

in your crontab 
. $HOME/.ssh/environment  && ssh -A blabla

If your server rebooted, you need run the start_agent scrit manually again

Comment: I find this dubious only because of the OP's comment that it tried finding a key in the correct home folder.

Comment: Is there any better way, such as copying the .ssh folder to the remote machine?

Comment: the easiest way is to remove password phase of your ssh key. you have to leverage security and convenience.

Answer (score 1):

You must set environment variable `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` on ssh client side in order to enable ssh-agent feature (where crontab doesn't set it for you).

```
*/x * * * * SSH_AUTH_SOCK=agent-sock-file ssh remote "command"
```

make sure the `agent-sock-file` exists when the crontab runs

Comment: Is there any better way, such as copying the .ssh folder to the remote machine?