# ssh command not working when script runs in crontab vs. manual command

Tags: bash, cron, sh

I'm creating a script that loops through a file of server names and checks the free space in /app of a server.  When I run the script via the command line, it runs fine.  However, when it runs via crontab, my main variable ($appData) isn't being set/stored.

I've tried just echo-ing the SSH command - it still doesn't return any information.

Script:

```
#!/bin/sh

inputFile ='/tmp/SpaceMonitoring/serverList.txt'
dos2unix $inputFile



output=/tmp/SpaceMonitoring/Logs/spaceResultsFull.$(date '+%F_%HH').txt

echo -e "Start Script [$(date '+%F %H:%M:%S %Z')] \n \n Local Drives:" > $output


while  read -r line|| [[ -n "$line" ]]; do 

    appText="/app"      
    appData=$(ssh -Aqno "StrictHostKeyChecking=no" $line "df -h | grep ' /app$'")   
    appFree=$(echo $appData | awk '{print $4}')     

    finalResApp=$(echo -e "\t$line \t $appText ($appFree) \n")  

    echo "$finalResApp" >> $output


done < "$inputFile" 

echo -e "\n End Script [$(date '+%F %H:%M:%S %Z')]" >> $output
```

Crontab:

```
00 10 * * * /tmp/SpaceMonitoring/checkSpace.sh
```

The output file via running it manually via the command line:

```
Start Script [2019-08-26 15:58:32 EDT] 

    server123    /app (86%)
    server234    /app (4%)

 End Script [2019-08-26 15:59:54 EDT]
```

The output file via running it via crontab:

```
Start Script [2019-08-26 15:58:32 EDT] 

    server123    /app ()
    server234    /app ()

 End Script [2019-08-26 15:59:54 EDT]
```

Comment: Take a look at openssh's option `-n`.

Comment: General notes: remove space from `inputFile =` line. To debug a cron job, redirect error output to a log file (and remove the `-q` option from ssh). Are you using `ssh-agent` authentication? If so, that won't be available from the cron job (unless you run an agent *in that job*); in any case, I'm pretty sure you don't want to forward the agent connection (`-A` option).

Comment: I have already added the -n variable here - we only have ssh on the servers - not openssh

Comment: Okay, try to replace `ssh` with `</dev/null ssh`.

Comment: @Cryus </dev/null ssh still didn't work

Comment: @Gordon how would i run the agent in that job?

Comment: The body of your loop looks like it wants to be a single Awk script. `while read -r line; dossh "$line" df /app; done <file | awk ...`

Comment: @Gia There are a lot of options, but all kind of ugly/insecure. The basic problem is that the cron job has to have access to everything needed to auth to those other computers, and making it available to cron may also make it available to other things. Some possibilities: use passwordless private key files (hopefully to a low-priv account, with [client-controlled command](https://serverfault.com/questions/749474/ssh-authorized-keys-command-option-multiple-commands)),

Comment: ... launch an agent within the cron job and [use ssh-add](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/cron-with-ssh-agent-ssh-add-and-keychain-4175607548/) there, run a user agent and somehow [give the job access to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12033249/ssh-agent-forwarding-inside-cron-jobs), and probably other methods.

Comment: Is the `/bin/sh` the same shell you run your command from? Did you try `/bin/bash`?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue, out of 100 hosts i ran an ssh command to, 3 failed to return any data, consistently, but only when run from cron. I found the solution to be increasing from the default ConnectTimeout (set by system). In my case i set it to 30 seconds, a lower number will probably be fine. So for your example, I would do as follows

appData=$(ssh -Aqno "StrictHostKeyChecking=no" -o ConnectTimeout=30 $line "df -h | grep ' /app$'")

This did resolve the same Issue I was having.